# Using -webkit-radial-gradient for glow

Tags: css, webkit

I'm trying to implement hover glow on custom button (see pic. below).
I'm playing in Chrome and can't achieve any similar look with -webkit-radial-gradient.
[image]

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      button {
        margin-top: 20px;
        width: 100px;
        height: 32px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        border-color:#D95D00;
        box-shadow: 0 0 4px #F3BB35 inset;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#D95D00), to(#E6A200));
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFD266), to(#F28430));
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom left top, from(#E97F2F), to(#F3BB35));
      }
      button:hover {
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#D95D00), to(#E6A200));
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFD266), to(#F28430));
        background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #FFFFFF, #000);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>Hello</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the button itself 'glow', or do you want a glowing border around its edge?

Comment: Make it glow itself. But seems all this gradients are bad idea, fonts are also not smooth.

Comment: If you'd settle for a glowing border instead due to the issues, then you can use the box-shadow property.

Answer (score 0):

It works pretty well with linear gradients. Radial gradients are similar: [dabblet](http://dabblet.com/gist/3303362).

You have to give your `background-image` (the gradient) a size (in any unit). Then you change one or more of these properties:

```
background-size: // to change the glow radius
background-position: // to change the center of the glow, pretty much analogue to linear gradient
background-color: // for partly transparent gradients
```